# Example of function where improper integral doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \colon [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, with $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) =0$. Does the integral \begin{equation*}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x\end{equation*} necessarily converge?

I think the answer is "no", because from $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$, the best bound we can get is that $\left\lvert f(x) \right\rvert \leq \epsilon$ for $x \geq \delta$ (where $\delta$ is some number $\geq 1$), but $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\epsilon}{x}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't converge. However, I couldn't find a specific example of $f$ for which the integral doesn't converge.

Comment: @Dayton It does not goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}$. It has limit $0$ at infinity and is continuous. But $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\ln (x+1)} \mathrm{d}x = +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a situation along the lines of $$\int_1^x \frac1{s\ln (2s)}\,ds=\ln\ln (2x)-\ln\ln2$$

Comment: This technically doesn't apply to my problem, as the domain needs to be $[1,\infty)$. But it is of course obvious how to modify it (as in the other answer above), so I still give an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & (1 \leqslant x \leqslant e), \\
1/\sqrt{\log{x}} & (x \geqslant e).
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0,$ and for all $a \geqslant e,$
\begin{align*}
\int_1^a\frac{f(x)}x\,dx & = \int_1^e\frac{f(x)}x\,dx + \int_e^a\frac{f(x)}x\,dx \\
& = \int_1^e\frac{1}x\,dx + \int_e^a\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\log{x}}}\,dx \\
& = \left[\log{x}\right]_1^e + \left[2\sqrt{\log{x}}\right]_e^a \\
& = 2\sqrt{\log{a}} - 1 \\
& \to \infty \text{ as } a \to \infty.
\end{align*}